# Create Java API from WSDL

Tags: java, api, soap, wsdl

I want to create java classes or use the API that is in this WSDL (https://secure.myclang.com/app/api/soap/public/wsdl/index.php?version=1.10) I tried axis2-1.6.2, but I didn't get it to work..

Someone can help me, or is something wrong with the WSDL?

Error that i get:

```
 C:\Users\Gynnad\Downloads\axis2-1.5.1-bin\axis2-1.5.1\bin>wsdl2java.bat -uri 
 https://secure.myclang.com/app/api/soap/public/wsdl/index.php?version=1.10
 Using AXIS2_HOME:   C:\Users\Gynnad\Downloads\axis2-1.6.2-bin\axis2-1.6.2
 Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31
 Retrieving document at 'https://secure.myclang.com/app/api/soap/public/wsdl/index.php?version=1.10'.
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger     (org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder).log4j:WARN Please initialize      the log4j system properly.
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:293)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(SimpleDBExtension.java:53)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:246)
    ... 2 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.extension.SimpleDBExtension.engage(SimpleDBExtension.java:50)
    ... 3 more
 Caused by: org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompilationException: can not find type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}Array from the parent schema https://secure.myclang.com/app/api/soap/public/index.php?version=1.10
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.copyMetaInfoHierarchy(SchemaCompiler.java:1371)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexContent(SchemaCompiler.java:1333)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processContentModel(SchemaCompiler.java:1228)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1172)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1092)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:1006)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:645)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:604)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.process(SchemaCompiler.java:2069)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processParticle(SchemaCompiler.java:1952)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1156)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processNamedComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1092)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:1006)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:645)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:604)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.process(SchemaCompiler.java:2069)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processParticle(SchemaCompiler.java:1952)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processComplexType(SchemaCompiler.java:1156)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processAnonymousComplexSchemaType(SchemaCompiler.java:1055)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processSchema(SchemaCompiler.java:1009)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:645)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.processElement(SchemaCompiler.java:615)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:423)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:292)
    at org.apache.axis2.schema.ExtensionUtility.invoke(ExtensionUtility.java:102)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: How did it "not work"?  What kind of answer are you looking for, a block of code that you can copy and paste?

Comment: @OscarGomez I added some errors!

Answer (score 2):

You can give this one a try:

[WSDL2JAVA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/)

EDIT:

Based on your errors, I believe the problem is with the WSDL itself:

```
org.apache.axis2.schema.SchemaCompilationException: can not find type {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}Array from the parent schema https://secure.myclang.com/app/api/soap/public/index.php?version=1.10
```

Comment: Using this I already tried before and I get this error: An error occurred while completing process -java.lang.InterruptedException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: @Gynnad I think the problem is with the WSDL and not the parser

Comment: I'm afraid too.. So there isn't a solution to use these WSDL in Java?

Comment: @Gynnad I am no expert on WSDL, but IMHO unless the WSDL is changed you will not be able to use it. You could try parsing it for other languages to make sure it is the WSDL and not something else.

Comment: Is it possible that this WSDL is only for a C-program en not for Java, or is this impossible?

Comment: @Gynnad That is impossible, WSDLs are not specific to any language.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

[Apache CXF - WSDL to Java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html)

It also have [Maven Plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) for doing the same